# Where to find a small version of frown in mathmode?

Tags: fonts, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I want to type `^` in mathmode, but `\frown` is too long, so my question is where to find a small version?

Update:
Thanks to Mico. I tried `\smallfrown`, but it seems too big either.

Comment: `amssymb` has `\smallfrown`. I found this just using detexify. Please check first this [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: {\scriptsize\frown} if another font does not suit you?

Comment: I tried {\scriptsize\frown} but things didn't change.

Comment: sorry I meant `\scriptstyle` not `\scriptsize`

Comment: OK, I tried it, and frown became smaller. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options for you that scales either `\frown` or `\smallfrown` (from [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb)) down to the size of `\textasciicircum`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\begin{document}
\textasciicircum $\frown$ \par
\textasciicircum \raisebox{.5em}{\smash{\scalebox{.5}{$\frown$}}} \par
\textasciicircum $\smallfrown$ \par
\textasciicircum \raisebox{.5em}{\smash{\scalebox{.5}{$\smallfrown$}}} \par
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, both `\frown` and `\smallfrown` is raised to the level of `\textasciicircum` for comparison using `\raisebox`, and scaled down to 50% of its original size (via `\scalebox` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).

Depending on the choice, you should define a command that creates the frown you're after, like

```
\newcommand*{\myfrown}{\raisebox{.5em}{\smash{\scalebox{.5}{$\smallfrown$}}}}
```

say.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `\smallfrown` (provided by the `amssymb` package)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it seems too big either. I want to seek a smaller on as ^.

Answer (score 0):

`\textasciicircum{}` or `\^{}` can be used within math mode using text mode

Check the link for symbols:

http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but \textasciicircum{} or \^{} cannot be used in mathmode.